# Why was this question bumped to the homepage?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18700/75000) is currently at the top of the main SFF homepage, and I'd like to know why. It says that it was active today, but I don't see any edits or additions past 2012, and it doesn't say anything about Community bumping it. So why was it pushed up?

Comment: You only need 6K more rep, then you'll see a whole new world!

Comment: @Möoz - A new craptastic point of view?

Comment: Yes, you'll see all the shite we've had to deal with.

Comment: @Valorum You can be someone to tell them no. And where to go. (Or at least where their posts will go.)

Answer (score 16):

There was a deleted answer one hour ago.

Only users with 10,000 or more reputation can see deleted answers, so that's probably the issue. However, everyone sees the same position in the Active queue.

Comment: This is correct, if you click on the 'active today' link, it takes you straight to that answer (if you have 10K+)

Comment: I'm so jealous!

Comment: @Valorum - When the content of a deleted answer is not pertinent to the question, I don't think it should be added.

Comment: @Adamant - Since the answer is about the deleted answer, I felt that that deleted post *was* pertinent. Regardless, it's in the edit history if anyone feels like they want to see it.

Comment: @Valorum - Yeah, but it doesn't have anything to do with what the answer is about, merely that there is *a* deleted answer.

Comment: @Adamant - Yes, but people shouldn't have to take your word for it.

Comment: or in other words, pics or it didn't happen